# Unable getValue() from Google visualization chart table

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I try make the alert prompt out window to shown  a  value from table row 1 and column 1 .[image: Table] , but none of the alert window prompt out.

**Here the table and dashboard draw code:**

```
        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'Table',
          'containerId': 'table_div',
                'options': {
            title: 'Table',
                    allowHtml: true
                     }, 
       'view': {'columns': [0,3,2,4,5,6,7,8]}
            
           });
            // Create the dashboard.
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker],[ table]);
        console.log(data)
                // Draw the dashboard
            dashboard.draw(data);
```

**alert prompt out window code**

```
 function showAlert() {
var dt = data.getDataTable();
 alert(dt.getValue(1, 1));   }showAlert();
```

Comment: The `showAlert()` should be called once the chart is loaded? - if so, you can alternatively add this code: `alert(data.getValue(1, 1));` *before* the `console.log(data);`

Comment: the code contain control wrapper and doing "WorkWeek" filter .If I filter the table by "WorkWeek" 15  , the getValue output  won't change .

Comment: Sorry, but, I don't understand. can you [edit] your question and provide the full code of the chart with sample data, please?